# MongoDB Aggregate not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mongodb, recursion, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to find all votes associated with a comment after a graphlookup but it isn't working.

I'm trying to get the comments/votes recursively of a thread.

I have 3 schemas:

comments

```
 - _id
 - points
- content
- userId
- parentId
- parentThreadId
```

threads

```
- _id
- upvotes
- downvotes
- title
- content
- userName
```

votes

```
- _id
- vote
- commentId
- userId
```

The problem is that a comment has two keys. One being 'parentId' and the other one 'parentThreadId'. parentId is only set if the comment is a child of another comment, and parentThreadId is set whenever it is a top-level comment under a thread.

Using this code, I only receive the votes associated with top-level comment (thus with a parentThreadId instead of the votes of all comments).

```
        const threadId = req.params.id;
        const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

        Thread.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {_id : ObjectId(threadId)}
            },            
            {
                $lookup:
                  {
                    from: 'comments',
                    as: 'comments',
                    pipeline: [ 
                        {
                            $match: {parentThreadId : ObjectId(threadId)}
                        }, 
                        {
                            $graphLookup: {
                                from: "comments",
                                startWith: "$_id",
                                connectFromField: "_id",
                                connectToField: "parentId",
                                as: "children",
                                depthField: "level",
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $lookup :
                            {
                              from: 'votes',
                              localField: '_id',
                              foreignField: 'commentId',
                              as: 'votes'
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                  }
             }
        ]).
```

Does anybody have a clue as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I get into similiar problem not a long ago, you have here recursive relationship between documents in one collection, and sadly, only way to get all tree of comments is recursievly make requests for each child level of comments.

Correct way to handle such stuff is to save all tree in topmost document, so you have thread, you need to save there in one property whole tree of comments, this way moving responsibility to manage it to js (where it is way easier to walk over such tree object, update it etc.)